# What are the consequences of too many unnecessary associations in rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-models

Sometimes it feels natural or is at least tempting to make model associations based on columns that *can* be associated. But that doesn't mean they *should* be associated.

What price does a database/app pay if there are too many unnecessary model associations?

What I know so far is that when we do something like `user:references` it creates a foreign key (and index on that key). So my guess is that it would be possible to bloat the database. But I have no idea how likely that is?

#### Minimal example

Suppose we have an airbnb type app, with hosts and guests. Suppose the `Payment` model records the host id and guest id in that table (technically it doesn't need to, since it would already associate with a Booking, which would already have the host and guest).

So in terms of app functionality, the Payment table doesn't need to have associations with the `Host` and `Guest` tables, but it could.

In circumstances where an association might create some conveniences, but is definitely not essential to the app, should we create the association?

Comment: In that example there really are few reasons to add the host_id and guest_id columns since you should be able to join to those tables through the other table (bookings) and avoid duplication and the bugs and complexity involved.

Comment: @max but that's the whole point. It's just an example of possibly saving the developer a little time. But the question is what impact do the unnecessary associations have on the app (e.g. performance wise)?

Comment: Its actually the opposite - you can just setup an indirect association and not have to deal with the migration in the first place. So I really dont agree with the premise here. Usually when people use to many foreign keys it's ignorance - not convenience.

Comment: @max This is very helpful, since it's definitely suggesting unnecessary associations should be veered away from (not toward). Is the only reason to avoid them because of the unnecessary complexity alone, or are there additional reasons? (e.g. performance)

Comment: Having to many indices can definitely slow things down. Its not really the associations themselves as that's an object oriented abstraction - going nuts on FKs will create a gnarly schema that's hard to reason about and you can get other issues like circular references .